# How to set "Document ID" file attribute property in Java?

Tags: java, file, windows-7, nio, windows-7-x64

I need to set "Document ID" file's property as seen in the Windows7 screenshot below
[image: Windows7 Choose Details Dialog]

I'm using [UserDefinedFileAttributeView](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/UserDefinedFileAttributeView.html) and created attribute "Document ID" on the file. I can write and read this attribute from the file with Java but Windows Explorer isn't showing it in the Detail View when I add this column.

Comment: Windows explorer(Windows 7) has many additional "details" available for files. You can see them all if you right click on any column name and "More". I'm asking how can I set additional file attributes matching these details.

Comment: I don't see anything unclear or incomplete about this question. Voted to reopen.

Comment: I suggest you list() the UserFileAttributeView of an existing file that has this attribute set and see how it's spelt. For example there may be no space.